# How to extend TextBox's properties to create a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

My Question is to how to extend a TextBox such that it may start behaving like RichTextBox?
There can be various properties that RichTextBox may add: appearance mainly.
Should I use this kind of method where I extend the TextBox class and create a basic TextBox which would contain several other textboxes which would behave like a big container node containing small specialized nodes?

For starters, to have texts with alternate color after '+', I ve used this way:

```
class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
 List<TextBox> _textboxes = new List<TextBox>();
 string _Text="";
 List<Color> colorlist = new List<Color>();
 public override string Text
 {
   get{return this._Text;}
   set{this._Text = value;}
 }
 public CustomTextBox()
 {
   foreach(Color color in (Color[]) Enum.GetValues(typeOf(Color)))
   {
     colorlist.add(color);
   }
   this.KeyUp+= new KeyUpEventHandler(TextChangedCheck);
 }
 int i=0;
 private void TextChangedCheck(object sender, KeyUpEventArgs e)
 {
   if(e.KeyData == Keys.Add)
   {
     TextBox Temp = new TextBox();
     Temp.Text = this.Text;
     this.Text = "";
     Temp.ForeColor = colorlist[i];
     i++;
     this._textboxes.Add(Temp);
     this.Controls.Add(_textboxes[i]);
     e.Handled = true;
   }
 }
}
```

**EDIT**:

The MAIN purpose of this question is to extend a TextBox using its own properties to have a RTB like behavior and not using Graphics or related.

Comment: Why not just use a RichTextBox?

Comment: I am trying to understand the limits of extending a TextBox

Comment: Then it is not a specific programming question

Comment: My purpose is not a specific programming question but 'my question' is a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to guess what you really want to achieve here.

But if you want a Control with formatted text (FT) and really really really don't want a RichTextBox, I think you shouldn't create a new, embedded TextBox for every piece of FT.

Instead you should write the FT yourself, maybe on a panel with DrawString and use only one Textbox for text entry. Interesting project, really, once one accepts the challenge. Of course you must think your format through and also consider all sorts of interface questions..

Last week I have avoided a RTF for a tiny help system by using a ListView; it formats by line only, using the first character to indicate the format from a list of a dozen or so.. Works fine, but only one format per line.

Comment: But that means every thing would be rewritten from scratch. Cant I reuse TextBox's properties and extend them. That would easier and a lot less 'buggy'.

Comment: Well, since the TextBox doesn't have any properties to format text in more than one way, what would you extend or reuse? You can reuse all its capabilities during text entry but all the display stuff simply insn't there. 

Can you define the extent of formating you need? 

And: can you explain why the RTF is a no-go for you?

Comment: Lets say, I am trying to understand the limits of extending a TextBox without using any other control/class/graphics.

Comment: To understand what can be used, look at the properties you inherit from TextBox and also from TextBoxBase. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
As you can see the is ONE Font, ONE ForeColor etc. So getting it to store and paint variations in formatting doesn't seem possible.

Comment: What about storing multiple TextBoxes as nodes for different formats. One can do that

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But you still will have to implement all the display logic, ie. move the textboxes to the right place, control their wraping etc.etc.. Not a small feat, I think.

Here is an interesting [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441009/Drawing-Formatted-Text-in-a-Windows-Forms-Applicat) for an altenative way to create formatted text. Not all that easy either..

Comment: Good link, though I was looking for something in Winforms, without WPF

Comment: The link actually uses Winforms and includes the WPF only to achieve its goal. But I would rather go for a RTF than play with such a mixture, myself.